# How to add customised page load events in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I would like to trigger page load event manually on specific areas in my code.Iam using jquery mobile,phonegap.

For Ex:

```
function jsonCallback(){
    // do some thing
    pageLoad('#page2');
}

pageLoad(){
    // trigger page2 load event
}

$(document).on("pageload", "#page2", function(e) {

});
```

EDIT: 
Iam using Phonegap deviceready event where database will be created

```
document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady, false );

function onDeviceReady() {
     //code to generate db
     //now i need to trigger the page1 pageshow event where it will fetch the result from database
}
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? pageload event can't be triggered manually. It can be done only through usage of $.mobile.loadPage()  and $.mobile.changePage() if another html files is opened. It cant't be used with internal # pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't trigger page events manually because they don't work like that.

They will trigger automatically only under some cases like page initialization or in your case when **[$.mobile.loadPage()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.loadPage/)** function is used.

Also I don't think you want to trigger **[pageload](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageload/)** event because, like I told you earlier it will trigger ONLY after **[$.mobile.loadPage()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.loadPage/)** function. That function don't accept **#** page as an parameter, instead a real html file must be provided.

Or you can initiate a changePage function like this:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#page2");
```

This function can be used with # page parameter. One more thing pageload event can also be triggered with **[$.mobile.changePage()](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/methods.html)** but only if another html file is opened, just like with 
**$.mobile.loadPage()** function.

**EDIT :**

Unfortunately your solution from comments will not work. Simply because you can pause page load. But nothing prevents you from cheating. Let your initial page be empty, use its page event to query DB and dynamically create index page. Then just changePage to #index page. This is the only way this can be done.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/g7S58/

In this example I am not querying the database because I don't have any but example is similar because I am creating a dynamical page content and appending it to the second #index page. This is the only way this will work without problems.

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="hidden">

        </div>   
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                <h1>Index page</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">

            </div>
        </div>          
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#hidden', function(e){ 
    $("<ul>").attr({'data-role':'listview','data-inset':'false','id':'mylist'}).append('<li><a>List element 1</a></li>').appendTo($('#index [ data-role="content"]'));
    $.mobile.changePage('#index');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Initially iam creating the database for offline storage.Once db has been created iam getting the callback method where i need to manually load the page.

Comment: Is it possible to load the internal html wherever i want it. for example i have index.html which contains 3 pages[page1,page2,page3]. I should be in a position to trigger the page load event manually

Comment: When you say load do you mean show? Because if you open index.html that have 3 pages all of them will be loaded. You only need to show them when needed.

Comment: Yes, i need to trigger the pageshow event in one method, and i need to add the functionality in different pageshow method.

Comment: Then just use $.mobile.changePage("#page2"); it will trigger page change thus triggering pageshow event for, in this case #page2 page.

Comment: by default jquery mobile will load the #page1, before that i need to popualte the db then i need to invoke the pageshow event.will changePage event fit in this scenario ?

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand you. Lets say #page1 is your first page to load. What do you want to happen?

Comment: on device ready iam creating a db structure, on callback of it, i need to manually trigger the page show event which will get the db results and populate it in the page1

Comment: is it possible to trigger the pageshow event of page2 from onDeviceReady method ?

Comment: I am rewriting my answer. Wait a bit please.